# Using SearchCursor and UpdateCursor to get multivalues from one table/field to single value of another table/field?

Tags: arcpy, dictionary, cursor

I'm trying to use a combination of `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` and `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` to read and store a couple of values from Table 1 Field A, then insert those values as a single string within Table 2 Field B.  So basically 2 values into 1.  There's a lot more to it of course, but this is the main piece I'm struggling to figure out.  I think I need to use a dictionary to store the values, but I'm honestly not too familiar with them.  That along with some list comprehension.

```
import arcpy

# Local Variables:
Table_1 = "C:\Path\TestArea.gdb\Table_1"
Table_2 = "C:\Path\TestArea.gdb\Table_2"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Table_1, "MILE_TEXT") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #Do something to grab the values in the MILE_TEXT field and concatenate them in preparation for the UpdateCursor

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Table_2, "MILE_MARKERS") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #Do something here to take the values collected in the SearchCursor and update a single field/cell with that value
        cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Complete Without Errors"
```

Here's a highlight of the data I'm trying to capture and use to populate
[image: Values Captured Here]

Here's the single cell I'm trying to populate with the captured values
[image: Captured Values Inserted Here]

Comment: With the addition of code, this is now a "How do I use dictionaries in Python?" question. There are heaps of tutorials on Python dictionaries on the web. Once you've become familiar with this concept you'll be ready to add the initialization, population, and lookup code and might not need any cursor-specific help to working code.

Comment: Thanks Vince.  I've combed through a lot of content that's out there on using dictionaries, but can't seem to get it to work.  What I find are a bunch of different ways to do it, which ends up confusing me even more.

Comment: So put what *doesn't* work in your code block here. There *are* many ways to solve this, so your attempt will make it easier to find a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, and sharing the code in case anyone runs into a similar situation and needs some sample code to get them started

```
import arcpy

River_Section = "C:\....<path to data>"
Adjacent_MileMarkers = "C:\....<path to data>"

scursor = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Adjacent_MileMarkers, ("MILE_TEXT"))]
print "List Comprehension value is: " + str(scursor)

i=0
ucursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(River_Section, ["MILE_MARKERS"])

for row in ucursor:      
    row[0] = str('Mile Marker:' + scursor[i] + ' to Mile Marker:' + scursor[i+1])
    ucursor.updateRow(row)

print "Script Complete"
```

Comment: This does not use best practice `with` to force closure of the cursor (or an explicit `del`), so the "Script Complete" assertion is questionable. You should also be using a dictionary in the misnamed `scursor` list.